# Symfony2 prices input and display

Tags: php, symfony

I've created form in Symfony2 with number field using [FormBuilder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html):

```
$builder->add('price', 'number');
```

Field is only properly processing numbers with "," (comma) used as decimal separator (per locale setting), but I want it to also parse numbers with "." (dot) used as decimal separator. Right now digits after "." (dot) are ignored.

What should I do to process both prices with both types of decimal separators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html), though I don't know how it renders.

Anyway you may try with a custom [Regex](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/Regex.html) validator constraint, asking for something like `number + dotOrComma + number`.

Or to sell your goods for free without price tag.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create a custom type, using the code of the core type as reference point.

See [this open feature request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2059) for reference.